# why my plotted graph is not showing up in PCA for iris dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, machine-learning, pca

I'm trying to plot a PCA graph of iris dataset but there is a blank graph showing up all the time. Where do I am committing the mistake?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-  databases/iris/iris.data"

df = pd.read_csv(url, names = ['sepal length', 'sepal width', 'petal length', 'petal width', 'target'])
df.head()

features = ['sepal length', 'sepal width', 'petal length', 'petal width']
x = df.loc[:, features].values
x[0:5]

y = df.loc[:, ['target']].values
y[0:5]

x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(x)

pca = PCA(n_components = 2)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(x)

principalDF = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents, columns = ['Principal Component 1', 'Principal Component 2'])

finalDF = pd.concat([principalDF, df[['target']]], axis = 1)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.set_xlabel('Principal Component 1', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_ylabel('Principal Component 2', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_title('2 Component PCA', fontsize = 20)

targets = ['Iris - setosa', 'Iris - versicolor', 'Iris - virginica']
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']

for target, color in zip(targets, colors):
    indicesToKeep = finalDF['target'] == target     # zip is used to map values , i.e, Iris - setosa = red(r) and likewise
    ax.scatter(finalDF.loc[indicesToKeep, 'Principal Component 1'],
              finalDF.loc[indicesToKeep, 'Principal Component 2'],
              c = color, s = 50)

ax.legend(targets)
ax.grid()
fig.savefig("PCA.png")
fig.show()
```

I expect the output of graph with scatter plots of three different colors but is blank out there[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mONqq.png)

Comment: Nothing happened...same result

Answer (score 0):

Just a very small mistake, your targets has spaces which is the cause of the problem. Put below:

```
targets = ['Iris-setosa', 'Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-virginica']
```

It will give you the plot as desired
[image]